# How to setup maintenance of line after each batch?

Tags: anylogic

I am new to anylogic and would like to create a model where a production line pack items into batches. After each batch, there is a 2hr maintenance needed, the line has to be stopped for 2hr before continuing with the next batch.

Here is what I did:

[image].

I tried creating a delay node to delay the batch but have no idea how to activate the node when a batch is complete and deactivate the node after 2hrs.

Comment: Hi LEO, strongly suggest you study all the step-by-step tutorials first, so you understand the basic concepts available. See https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html